# Changing datetime format in py

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I have the following code which gives the following output:

```
print(df1['Diff'].mean())
```

outputs:

```
10 days 16:13:29.467455
```

But since i just want the days value and not the time, i have done this:

```
print(datetime.strptime(df1['Diff'].mean(), format ='%d')
```

but i am getting the following error:

```
                    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Why am i getting this error?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `df1['Diff'].mean().strftime('%d')`? [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime)

Comment: Thanks but i am getting `AttributeError: 'Timedelta' object has no attribute 'strptime'` when i tried that?

Comment: @SunnyPatel yes you are right! but still error : `print(datetime.strftime(df1['Diff'].mean(), format ='%d'))
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strftime'`

Comment: Updated my answer, based on the information for timedelta object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For `date`, `time`, and `datetime` objects

You should be using `strftime` to *format* the time, not to *parse* the time (as in `strptime`).

```
print(obj.strftime('%d'))
```

`strptime` expects a string to be passed in (and you were passing in a `datetime` object), whereas `strftime` formats an existing `datetime` object.

### For `timedelta` objects

```
print(obj.days)
```

This gets the days counterpart you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think the instance of `df1['Diff'].mean()` is `str` and `datetime.strptime()` can be use only in `datetime` methods. So to only get date you have to take slice of `df1['Diff'].mean()` like `df1['Diff'].mean()[:-14]`
Which is in your case.

Comment: That made sense but the error says: `    print(df1['Diff'].mean()[:-14])
TypeError: 'Timedelta' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: So it is Timedelta object then simply write print(str(df1['Diff'].mean())[:-14])